# Location of Controller in Laravel

Tags: laravel, laravel-7

I created a new Laravel controller named "StoriesController" using the CLI:

```
php artisan make:controller StoriesController
```

When I open app/Http/Controllers/StoriesController.php, I see:

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;

class StoriesController extends Controller
{
    //
}
```

My question is about the line:

```
class StoriesController extends Controller
```

Where is the "Controller" script located? Which directory?

Comment: in the same directory as `StoriesController`, its in the same namespace ... once you open that you will then be looking for the class that that class extends which is part of the framework

Comment: Yes, you're right. Thank you. If you want to post as an answer, I'll accept it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
{your-project]/app/http/controllers/{StoriesController}
```

[image]